# Отображение названия при выборе категории

Tags: ajax, php

При выборе любой категории мне нужно, чтобы ее название отображалось выше в разделе выбрано Как это сделать на ajax, без обновления страницы?

[image]

Comment: "Нужно решение" это Вам не сюда. Что делаете? Что не получается?

Comment: Честно говоря еще пока что не делал. Жду когда верстальщик сверстает эту страницу.
Попозже буду делать. Но пока не придумал как. Вот и спрашиваю.

Comment: Юзайте jQuery, и будет вам щастье!

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery, функции:](http://jquery-docs.ru/)

**click** - событие клика на (ремонт, покраска).

**val** - достать значение с кликнувшего элемента.

**toggle** - показать-скрыть, можно поставить slow и будет медленно двигаться(красиво) а также если убрать то исчезать.